# How can I link multiple customers to an 'Actie-object'?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-models

Here are the imports:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

This is the first class i did define. It is the status of the action (Actie) and it has a status-id and a status-name with a max_length attribute of 5 (todo, doing, done)

```
class Status(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
status_naam = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='todo')

def __str__(self):
return str(self.id) + " - " + self.status_naam
```

This is the class Actie (Action or the action the user determines) which has an id, an action-name, a action-status which refers to the table Status here above, an action-publish-date, an ending-date (the deadline) and a user-id which refers to the table Users django gives me.

```
class Actie(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
actie_naam = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='-')
actie_status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default=1)
actie_aanmaakdatum = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
actie_einddatum = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
actie_gebruiker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
return str(self.id) + " - " + self.actie_naam
```

My question now is what do I have to do to link multiple Users to an Actie? Because now I can link only one User to an Actie.

Comment: Can a user be linked to more than one Actie?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Then you need a ManyToManyField, not a ForeignKey.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Then you need a ManyToManyField, not a ForeignKey. – Daniel Roseman"

This solved my problem.